# mysql left outer join

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, join, left-join

i have some sql table

```
table classes(id_classes,specialty,level)
table Teaching unit(id_unit,name,...,#id_classes)
table courses(#id_course,....,#id_unit)
table groupes(id_groupe,...,#id_classes)
table assignment(#id_groupe,#id_course)
```

i want to find courses which not in assignment for a given groupe
so this courses are depending to unit that depend to the groupe's classe

i wrote this code

```
select * from courses c
left join assignment a
on a.idcourse=c.idcourse and a.id_groupe ='given  id'
where a.id_courses is null
```

but this return the courses depend to all classes that not in assignment

### Additional Info (copied from comment)

for exempl i have a classe with id 1 and classe with id 2 groupe with id 1 courses 1 ,2 and 3 depend to unit 1 thats depent to classe 1 courses 4,5 and 6 depend to unit 2 that depend to classe 2 i have a groupe 1 depend to classe 1 in the table asignement i have 2 rows (groupe1,courses1),(groupe1,courses2) i want to make a query that return the courses 3 that still not assigned to the groupe 1 the query return courses 3,4,5,and 6 but i want to get only the courses 3

```
select c.* from courses c ,unit u where  (courses not in asignment where id_groupe=given id) and u.idunit=c.idunit and u.classes is the same classes form the given groupe
```

Comment: I'm not following... can you please share some sample data, the results you're getting, and the desired results?  The query you have written will return all courses that don't have a record in assignment, which sounds like what you're trying to get.

Comment: this query return all the courses that are not in the table assignement and i want only to get the crouses depend to the same classe of the given groupe

Comment: for exempl i have a classe with id 1 and classe with id 2
groupe with id 1
courses 1 ,2 and 3 depend to unit 1 thats depent to classe 1
courses 4,5 and 6 depend to unit 2 that depend to classe 2
i have a groupe 1 depend to classe 1
in the table asignement i have 2 rows (groupe1,courses1),(groupe1,courses2)
 i want to make a query that return the courses 3 that still not assigned to the groupe 1
the query return courses 3,4,5,and 6 but i want to get only the courses 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your description your left join is not incorrect is that you didn't have any code that expresses your extra contraints "u.idunit=c.idunit and u.classes is the same classes form the given groupe"

This should be the code you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM courses c
LEFT JOIN assignment a ON c.id_course = a.id_course
INNER JOIN teachingUnit u ON u.id_unit = c.id_unit 
                            AND u.id_classes IN (SELECT id_classes
                            FROM groupes
                            WHERE id_groupe =  ‘givenID’)
WHERE a.id_course IS NULL AND a.id_groupe = ‘givenID’
```

this sub query

```
 (SELECT id_classes
   FROM groupes
   WHERE id_groupe =  ‘givenID’)
```

handles the constraint of u.classes is the same classes form the given groupe.
The `INNER JOIN` on `teachingUnit u ON u.id_unit = c.id_unit` handles the constraint of "and u.idunit=c.idunit"

I hope this helps. Because in your example your table name and columns are inconsistent and your objective is hard to understand. This solution is the best I can come up with minimal assumptions that were made out of neccesity.

Comment: @rammeh-nasr I looked at your suggested edit. The sql you suggested is invalid. You can't have `WHERE` clause between `JOINS`. But I did simplify the code. Let me know if it works. if it does please mark my response as the answer to help the community so people know this question is answered. If not please let me know what went wrong.